# System Variable path is different in command prompt

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, registry, environment-variables

I've seen different kind of problems around, but I'm fighting with this for a whole day, so please give me some help :)

*Short story*: I have different PATH variable in System Variables panel and cmd. Can't run exe files?

*Longer story*: I'm trying to install Ruby. Tried with different versions, but the problem is the same: I **have** my PATH value updated, Ruby is there. **BUT** when using it from cmd, ruby is not recognized. `echo %PATH%` **gives different value from the one in Environment Variables panel!**

First attachment: Environment Variables panel:

[image]

Values for **user** variables:
`C:\Users\morifey\nvmw\nodejs\v0.10.36;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;"C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\";"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64";"C:\Program Files\nodejs\";C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;"C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd";"C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\";"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\";C:\Users\morifey\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Ruby21\bin`

Value for **system** variables:
`C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\Users\morifey\nvmw\nodejs\v0.10.36;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;"C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\";"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64";"C:\Program Files\nodejs\";C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;"C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd";"C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\";"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\";"C:\Users\morifey\AppData\Roaming\npm";%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%`

I compare them to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment* - they are **all the same**.

**BUT** I run cmd and use `echo %PATH%`. Results:
`C:\Users\morifey\nvmw\nodejs\v0.10.36;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Win
dows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPow
erShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Int
el\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\In
tel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C
:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\b
in;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Fi
les\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users
\morifey\AppData\Roaming\npm`

**Ruby is missing!** It's the same for both run as administrator and not (actually I have single administrator user).

I've tried setting path (via set or setx), changing both registries AND environmental variables - nothing is working. I've tried adding quotes (`"`) in paths that have spaces - no difference.

**Except** if I run cmd as administrator and use `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Ruby21\bin"`! Then, `echo %PATH%` returns the **real** (updated) path, and I am able to run `ruby` **ONLY** in this cmd. If I close it, and reopen it again as admin - changes are lost.

Please give me any kind of advise how to deal with this? I just need to run Ruby :)

Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1, 64-bit;
Downloaded Ruby (from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) - Ruby 2.2.2 (32 & 64 bit), Ruby 2.1.6 (32 & 64 bit) - results are all the same.

---

*Edit*: After few guys said I don't need quotes, I've removed them, and placed exactly what @eryksun said. This is the result:

`C:\Users\morifey>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\morifey\nvmw\nodejs\v0.10.36;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Win
dows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPow
erShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Int
el\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\In
tel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C
:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\b
in;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Fi
les\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users
\morifey\AppData\Roaming\npm`

It's pretty weird some of the inputs are repeating:

`C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;`

**despite** they are not like that in the lines I've pasted in the System Variables Path!

---

*Update* - I've used PowerShell and [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-check-for-duplicate-5d9dd711) script to check if there is a repetition in the system variables. I'm uploading image with the result. It's **pretty strange** that the path is exactly what should be, but as you can see, in CMD I see different thing!

[image]

---

**Update** - Today I tried running Ruby from PowerShell - all worked out. So it seems like only CMD doesn't know what's going on! And just to remind you - rebooting does not help! :)

Comment: Sign out and in (or restart).

Comment: Restart does not help. I've tried restarting each time after I uninstall Ruby, then after I installed the new one, then after I change the %PATH% in any way. Every time the results are all the same.

Comment: Remove all `"` double quotes from both user and system `path` environment variable setting (using GUI, **no** `setx`).  Those are considered harmful there. [Read more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/29/776926.aspx).

Comment: I've seen few posts saying spaces *anywhere* are not a good practice. I've added the quotes manually. I've removed them *manually from System Variables* - nothing's changed.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates between the user and system `PATH`? That should never be the case. These two values get merged at logon. It looks like the user `PATH` should just contain `C:\Users\morifey\nvmw\nodejs\v0.10.36;C:\Users\morifey\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Comment: And clean up the mess in your system `PATH`. For example: `%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\Ruby21\bin`.

Comment: I've edited the question because it was too long for comment. It's weird that I paste something into the input field, and then after `echo %PATH%` I get very different value. Note the repetition of entries, which is pretty weird!

Comment: As I stated in the update - I've replaced both of them with exactly what you've provided, so now my use PATH is only for npm and nodejs. There is no overlapping between them. And as you can see - PowerShell gets the PATH properties correctly. Registries are correct and System Variables window shows correct values. But it's the command prompt that's messed up and so trying to run something (in my case Ruby) ends up with failure..

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you specify your Ruby path in your .bashrc file* (PATH=C:\Ruby21\bin:$PATH) and source it? *Or whatever bash config file your windows system has.

Comment: The PowerShell excursions and screen shots are distracting. We need to see the two registry values and current `%PATH%`, which you can copy (preferrably not a screenshot; just copy and paste as a code block) from the output of the following command: `reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH & reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environ
ment" /v PATH & echo %PATH%`.

Comment: Also check `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" & reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"`. The interest here is primarily the `AutoRun` value if it exists. Something could be running that's modifying `PATH`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with a bat file that run each time I started `cmd`, and it modified it's variables! Thanks to @eryksun and @ılǝ - it seems that in the registry (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`) you might have something like that. My problem was with **nvmw** package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvmw) that when installed, created this .bat file and stored my current PATH variable. Then it was setting it to the cmd *every time* I use it, and so it never got updated.
You can see the issue I've created here: https://github.com/nanjingboy/nvmw/issues/5

*SHORT STORY*: check your `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`, and **DO NOT USE NVMW** package!

Comment: This has solved an issue I've had for over a year that was preventing me from using Qt Creator. Thank you so incredibly much!

Comment: I just had this issue trying work out why Anaconda was appearing in my path. Turns out Andaconda sets AutoRun to run condabin\conda_hook.bat

Answer (score 1):

If your system variable PATH length is longer than some value, it is truncated in cmd prompt. According to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/719459/strange-path-issue-in-windows-7-goes-null-after-being-set) this value is 2047. Remove duplicates and trim your path, you will see that both variables will be same.

Comment: It's easy to see that my PATH is no longer than 2047. In fact, it's 669 characters - way below the limit. But as you can see from the images, it's not that it's truncated, it's **different**!

Answer (score 1):

When you use SET operand, it changes environment variables only of current console,  it is that what it for. To change environment variables permanent, you should use command SETX. And reboot windows. The 
Technicaly,  you can not reboot, just restart all services, but easily reboot.

Comment: If you read my detailed explanation you'll see that I've used `setx`, but it worked **only for current cmd prompt**. Restart does not help (as stated few times). It's only cmd that reads wrong path - everything else seems legit.

Comment: Ou. Then it is should be length limit, like Atilla Ozgur said. In windows Path saved in Unicode format(your size*2), and User's variables merged with System's vars.
After merge it probably overflow length limit and discard merge.

Answer (score 1):

I do software packaging for automatic deployment, and sometimes there are applications that need their folder setup in %PATH% and for that I use this Powershell script.
It checks to see if the folder is there already (so you won't have duplicates) and also removes it if needed (ie for silent uninstall).

You use **ADD-PATH** to add a folder and **REMOVE-PATH** to remove it.
Works like a charm.

```
#REQUIRES -Version 3.0

<#
.SYNOPSIS
    A script to add or remove folders to %PATH%
.DESCRIPTION
    It contains 2 functions, one for adding and one for removing. It reads the registry and does the modifications there.
.NOTES
    File Name      : AddRemovePath.ps1
    Author         : Iulian Dita (iulian.dita@gmail.com)
    Prerequisite   : PowerShell V3 over Vista and upper.
    Copyright 2015 - Iulian Dita
.LINK
    Script located at:
    \\%server%\dsm2$\Work\Master\Projects\29532\Extern$
.VERSION
    0.7
.VERSION_HISTORY
    0.1 Initial version
    0.2 Bug fixes
    0.3 Cosmetic fixes, automatic removal of preceding ";"
    0.4 Fixed double entries
    0.5 Kill Explorer and CMD processes before making any modifications
    0.6 Check if folder to be removed already exists in PATH
        Escaping special characters no longer needed for the removal function
    0.7 Cleaned the code and removed some syntax missmatches
        Included the sendmessage function to avoid killing the explorer task
        Used [reges]::escape() to avoid running into troubles with the path-string and -match methode
        Contributed by Maik Krammer
#>

if (-not ("win32.nativemethods" -as [type])) {
    # import sendmessagetimeout from win32
    add-type -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
   IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam,
   uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
"@
}

$HWND_BROADCAST = [intptr]0xffff;
$WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
$result = [uintptr]::zero

function global:ADD-PATH
{
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param ( 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, Position=0)] 
        [string] $Folder
    )

    # See if a folder variable has been supplied.
    if (!$Folder -or $Folder -eq "" -or $Folder -eq $null) { 
        throw 'No Folder Supplied. $ENV:PATH Unchanged'
    }

    # Get the current search path from the environment keys in the registry.
    $oldPath=$(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path

    # See if the new Folder is already in the path.
    if ($oldPath | Select-String -SimpleMatch $Folder){ 
        return 'Folder already within $ENV:PATH' 
    }

    # Set the New Path and add the ; in front
    $newPath=$oldPath+';'+$Folder
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newPath -ErrorAction Stop

    # Show our results back to the world
    return 'This is the new PATH content: '+$newPath

    # notify all windows of environment block change
    [win32.nativemethods]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE, [uintptr]::Zero, "Environment", 2, 5000, [ref]$result)
}

function global:REMOVE-PATH {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param ( 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, Position=0)]
        [String] $Folder
    )

    # See if a folder variable has been supplied.
    if (!$Folder -or $Folder -eq "" -or $Folder -eq $NULL) { 
        throw 'No Folder Supplied. $ENV:PATH Unchanged'
    }

    # add a leading ";" if missing
    if ($Folder[0] -ne ";") {
        $Folder = ";" + $Folder;
    }

    # Get the Current Search Path from the environment keys in the registry
    $newPath=$(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path

    # Find the value to remove, replace it with $NULL. If it's not found, nothing will change and you get a message.
    if ($newPath -match [regex]::Escape($Folder)) { 
        $newPath=$newPath -replace [regex]::Escape($Folder),$NULL 
    } else { 
        return "The folder you mentioned does not exist in the PATH environment" 
    }

    # Update the Environment Path
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newPath -ErrorAction Stop

    # Show what we just did
    return 'This is the new PATH content: '+$newPath

    # notify all windows of environment block change
    [win32.nativemethods]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE, [uintptr]::Zero, "Environment", 2, 5000, [ref]$result)
}


# Use ADD-PATH or REMOVE-PATH accordingly.

#Anything to Add?

ADD-PATH "%_PATH_TO_BE_ADDED%"

#Anything to Remove?

ADD-PATH "%_PATH_TO_BE_REMOVED%"
```

I didn't create this script from scratch, I found pieces on line and adapted them to my needs.

EDIT: I updated the code a bit, you no longer have to escape the backslashes or care about **;** in front, and also other useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the Command Prompt autorun (command prompt setting the PATH on run):
https://superuser.com/questions/727316/error-in-command-line-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified